# plot shapefile variable: Error invalid gray level, must be in [0,1]. R

Tags: r, regression

I have a shapefile which I have run through a spatial regression model in R.

I have pulled out the residuals from the regression model and added them as a new variable to the original shapefile. I am hoping to map these residuals but am encountering some issues.

Here is my code:

```
     plot(shapefile,col=gray(shapefile@data$residuals))
```

I am receiving this error:

```
  invalid gray level, must be in [0,1].
```

Am I correct in assuming this is to do with the values of the residuals? They span from -40 to +20. Is there a way to change this scale from 0-1 to a larger scale? or an easier way to plot these please?

I have also tried spplot:

```
     spplot(shape@data$residuals)
```

and receive the error:

```
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spplot’ for signature 
  ‘"numeric"’
```

Comment: Aye the `gray()` function needs the first parameter to be [0,1] bounded. You can use `scales::rescale()` to scale your [-40,20] to [0,1]

Comment: Unless you are printing in black and white, its usually better to plot residuals with a *diverging* palette so 0 is a neutral colour, and maybe reds are +ve and blues are -ve. You might also look at the `tmap` package for mapping spatial data.

Answer (score 0):

`col = grey()` produces HEX codes for grey scale based on the values placed inside. Yes, these numbers should be between 0:1. If you are trying to get an individual grey HEX code for each unique residual, you can do this by using the `length` and `unique` function. Below is an example where we have different grey scale for each group is our data frame:

```
Group <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Year <- c(2006,2007,2008,2009,2006,2007,2008,2009,2006,2007,2008,2009)
Qtr.1 <- as.numeric(c(15,13,22,13,12,16,13,23,11,15,17,14))
DF <- data.frame(Group,Year,Qtr.1)

#to get HEX for each unique input
c <- grey(1:length(unique(DF$Group))/length(unique(DF$Group)))

c
> [1] "#555555" "#AAAAAA" "#FFFFFF"

 #Without Grey
plot(DF$Year,DF$Qtr.1)

#With Grey
plot(DF$Year,DF$Qtr.1, col = c[Group])
```

Note that I didn't make a choice about the grey HEX codes that were produced, and group 3's HEX code is so faint that is hard to spot. Also, we needed to index on `Group` at the end of the `col` argument. As others have mentioned, there are likely better ways to go about this than grey scale and the base plot function. Looking towards other packages is likely a better option for customized visualization (i.e. ggplot or what others have noted).

Check this nice [summary](https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/plotcolors.html) for more info on `col`